# How automatically change currentCustomerGroup for not logged-in users in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to show different prices based on IP detection. I want to automatically change the preloaded customer group and show prices and all cart calculations for this group. I can't find any way to change this. Any ideas?

I have subscriber on the event:  GenericPageLoadedEvent::class => 'onPageLoaded'  and I need to find way to change currentCustomerGroup and force Shopware to recalculate prices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if changing the default customer group at a later stage could be problematic, so keep that in mind.

In theory you could subscribe to two events. First of all you may listen to `SalesChannelContextCreatedEvent` to change the `currenCustomerGroup` as early on as possible.

This will however be problematic when you're using the http cache, as normally a sales channel will have only one default customer group if there's no logged-in customer at the time. Hence why the customer group is not part of the cache key. You'll have to manually add an additional parameter to the cache key, which determines if the current user was routed in one or the other customer group by their IP.

I assume you're using rules for the prices by customer group. In that case you don't have to worry about the object cache.

Here's the general idea for a subscriber that handles both the change of customer group and enhancing the http cache key:

```php
class SalesChannelContextSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    // constructor etc ...

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SalesChannelContextCreatedEvent::class => 'onSalesChannelContextCreated',
            HttpCacheGenerateKeyEvent::class => 'onHttpCacheGenerateKey',
        ];
    }

    public function onSalesChannelContextCreated(SalesChannelContextCreatedEvent $event): void
    {
        // check ip, create criteria to fetch one or the other customer goup, etc...

        // fetch customer group according to ip
        $customerGroup = $this->customerGroupRepository
            ->search($criteria, $event->getContext())
            ->first();

        $event->getSalesChannelContext()->assign([
            'currentCustomerGroup' => $customerGroup,
        ]);
    }

    public function onHttpCacheGenerateKey(HttpCacheGenerateKeyEvent $event): void
    {
        // check ip and map ips to unique cache parameters...

        $additionalCacheParam = 'depending on ip';

        $originalHash = $event->getHash();
        $newHash = hash('sha256', $originalHash . '-' . $additionalCacheParam);
        $event->setHash($newHash);
    }
}
```